# Why did Star Trek: The Next Generation season 2 only have 22 episodes?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes

In the Star Trek franchise shows *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* and *Star Trek: Voyager*, each show almost always had 26 episodes per season.  Besides [*Voyager*'s first season](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/250785/141465), the only exception in this is the second season of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, which instead had 22.  Why is this?

Comment: What, you wanted *more* Pulaski episodes?

Comment: I was hoping for one where she fell down an elevator...

Comment: That's turbolift, Harper.

Comment: @HamSandwich Or maybe Harper meant she'd go back in time...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because of the [1988 Writer's Guild of America Strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_Writers_Guild_of_America_strike). Technically it occurred at the very end of the previous season, but the next season was impacted more heavily because the producers weren't able to consult with the writing team on the upcoming scripts.

In the end they padded out the season out to 24 episodes by recycling [a TOS script](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Phase_II#.22The_Child.22), adding a [clip show](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shades_of_Gray_(episode)) and showing a '[Star Trek TOS -> Star Trek TNG](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Trek_Saga:_From_One_Generation_To_The_Next)' two-hour special hosted by Patrick Stewart.

Extensively discussed in this series of interviews:

Answer (score 7):

**There was a [writers' strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_Writers_Guild_of_America_strike) in 1988.**

The Writers´ Guild of America went out on strike in the spring and summer of 1988. They demanded more creative control and residuals for the shows they wrote.

The writers of ST:TNG at Paramount joined in despite their Sacred Duty.

The strike ended on August 7, but the production pipeline was adversely affected, and ST:TNG wasn't able to start airing until November 21. (This episode, "The Child", contained the first appearance of Whoopi Goldberg playing Guinan.)